# Failed PowerBI API access with certificate thumbprint

Tags: azure, powershell, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

In order to use the PowerBI API in Powershell, I've set up an Azure App and installed a certificate.

I try to connect to the API this way:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxxxxxxxx" -ApplicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

However, I only get this not very helpful error:

```
„At least one error occured.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.ConnectPowerBIServiceAccount“
```

Any hints what might be missing?

Comment: See if [Resolve-PowerBIError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.profile/resolve-powerbierror?view=powerbi-ps) helps share any more details.

Comment: It says "Unable to find a certificate with thumbprint 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in CurrentUser or LocalMachine certificate stores"
I thought, I was all set by adding the certificate to the Azure App.

Comment: Could you include what PowerShell commands you used to create the certificate?

Comment: @Sridevi: I did not create it with PS, it was done by the IT dept using Azure portal

Comment: In my case, I used PowerShell commands mentioned in this MS Doc to create certificate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-create-self-signed-certificate#create-and-export-your-public-certificate and uploaded it to Azure app registration.

Answer (score 0):

I registered one application named *PowerBiDec* and added certificate to it as below:

[image]

Initially, I too got **same error** when I tried to connect Power BI with certificate thumbprint:

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxxxxxxxx" -ApplicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, I followed below steps by closing all open PowerShell sessions and deleted all ***MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt*** modules(folders) manually and install again.

Make sure to **enable** below settings in your Power BI Admin portal that allows access to service principal:

[image]

Now, I ran these PowerShell commands as ADmin and connected to Power BI with certificate thumbprint successfully:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Unregister-PSRepository -Name PSGallery
Register-PSRepository -Default

Find-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt 

Install-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -force -AllowClobber

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxxxxxxx" -ApplicationId "xxxxxxx"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below command, I got **access token**  in response like this:

```
Get-PowerBIAccessToken | fl
```

**Response:**

[image]

**References:**

[(PowerShell) Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount not... - Microsoft Fabric Community by **agneum**](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/PowerShell-Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount-not-working/m-p/2655558#M37508)

[Connecting PowerBI from Power Shell without pr... - Microsoft Fabric Community by **kranthi_sunkara**](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Connecting-PowerBI-from-Power-Shell-without-prompting/m-p/2518709)

Comment: I tried it on a fresh machine, that had no PBI modules installed. Same result: "Unable to find a certificate with thumbprint 'xxxxxxxxxxx' in CurrentUser or LocalMachine certificate stores"
Do I have to install the certificate on my local machine?

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of your Azure App and it's thumbprint?

Comment: It's the first screenshot added in above answer

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I have. But did you have to install the certificate on you local machine's cert store as well?

Comment: I used these PowerShell commands to create certificate and exported to local drive like this: $certname = "powerbi"    
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256
Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:/test/$certname.cer"

Comment: But how is this new self-signed certificate related to the Azure App?

Comment: In my case, I uploaded this new self-signed certificate to the Azure AD App registration. Then, it worked when I signed in with `Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxxxxxxx" -ApplicationId "xxxxxxx"`.

Comment: Are you using different method to set up an Azure App and installing certificate?

Comment: Our internal Azure admins have set up the App and the certificate. I thought it would suffice to have the thumbprint in order to authenticate and use the API. Unfortunately I'm not quite familiar with the certification stuff. Do I have to deploy anything on my local machine?

Comment: You can try creating certificate on your local machine by running this PowerShell commands: $certname = "powerbi" $cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "CN=$certname" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -KeySpec Signature -KeyLength 2048 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -HashAlgorithm SHA256 Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath "C:/test/$certname.cer"

Comment: Then create new app registration in Azure AD and upload this certificate to that app registration. After sometime, try running `Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -ServicePrincipal -CertificateThumbprint "xxxxxxxxxx" -ApplicationId "xxxxxxx"`

Comment: I downloaded the App's certificate as .csr and installed it in my local machine, but now it says "The certificate certificate does not have a private key". I'm completely lost :(

Comment: I also created the self-signed cert an uploaded it to the App, but to no results. Same error.